# How to see all packets in the air with scapy on Windows?

Tags: python, wifi, scapy, sniffing

I am trying to sniff some packets in python 3.4 in `scapy`.

I am using Windows 8.1, and I know that the `socket` module does not have a `PF_PACKET` or something like on Windows to sniff packets, so i used the `scapy.sniff` function. I have already installed WinPcap 4.1.3 .

I tried to sniff and was surprised that it only sniffs packets from the wireless network that I am connected to right now, so if i am not connected to any network it will not sniff anything (I have been waiting for 10 mins, and it didn't print anything). The code:

```
from scapy.all import sniff, tshark
pkts = sniff(count=30) # iface does not work
```

`tshark` is the same as `sniff`, gives the same results.

I have an ALFA wireless realtek interface card, it supports monitor mode.

Is there a solution here? Does `wspy` (wireshark in python) work in Windows? Does it support WiFi monitor mode?

Comment: _"only sniffs packets from the network that i am connected to right now , so if i am not connected to any network it will not sniff anything"_ -- how is that unexpected? Naturally, you can only get packets that your network card physically receives.

Comment: so, how am i going to see all the packets that are in the air near my PC ? i want to sniff all the packets that are in the air .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scapy has support for monitor mode, but it requires several things:

- Use the latest development scapy version. To download it, get https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip and install it via `python setup.py install`
- Use Npcap instead of Winpcap. You will need to uninstall Winpcap first (Winpcap has been abandoned, and Nmap took the project back). Download it at https://nmap.org/npcap/
- Call `sniff([...], monitor=True)`. It will be safer to specify the interface. You can print the list with `IFACES.show()` in scapy’s console. (*Note: the interface name `iface=` argument allows full interface name. For instance “RaLink Adapter (R) Wi-Fi” as prompted by the previous command*)

The monitor argument is important, as it triggers new sniffing mechanics.

Wireshark will also requires Npcap (Winpcap has no support for monitor mode) to sniff in monitor mode

Comment: You don't need to download a `.zip`, [`pip` can install directly from a Git repository](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git): `pip install git+https://github.com/secdev/scapy`.

Comment: True, but this will require pip to `git clone` the thousands of commits, and takes much longer. You can try it yourself to check